# Combining two nodesets in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <elem>Timestamp</elem>
    <elem>ERB.CHW.BTU_CV</elem>
    <elem>ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV</elem>
    <elem>ERB.HW.BTU_CV</elem>
    <elem>ERB.HW.BTU1_CV</elem>
    <elem>ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV</elem>
    <elem>ERB.KWH.MT_CV</elem>
    <elem></elem>
  </row>
  <row>
    <elem>2011/09/30 11:21:13.9062</elem>
    <elem>2.307609E+09</elem>
    <elem>1880067</elem>
    <elem>1.068635E+08</elem>
    <elem>1340.386</elem>
    <elem>448.8</elem>
    <elem>1427723</elem>
    <elem></elem>
  </row>
</root>
```

I want to alter it such that the first `<row>` defines new elements (via `<elem>`) and each non-empty `<elem>` that follows provides values - such as:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <Timestamp>2011/09/30 11:21:13.9062</Timestamp>
    <ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>2.307609E+09</ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>
    <ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>1880067</ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>
    <ERB.HW.BTU_CV>1.068635E+08</ERB.HW.BTU_CV>
    <ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>1340.386</ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>
    <ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>448.8</ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>
    <ERB.KWH.MT_CV>1427723</ERB.KWH.MT_CV>
  </row>
</root>
```

Two things to note:

1. Notice how blank `<elem>` elements are removed from the source structure.
2. This should work for any number of `<row>` nodesets.

I feel like this should be simple, but I'm struggling to even know where to begin.  Help?

**EDIT:** RE: #2 above, I am not looking to duplicate the initial `<row>` nodeset (which is used to define the new elements).  Rather, the solution should work for any `<row>` nodeset that contains data points (i.e., if the second `<row>` nodeset was duplicated 5 times in a row).

Comment: ABach, Sorry, I don't understanr your Edit. It is best to give (in the question) an example of the particular XML and the wanted result. Do you mean that the element names are always defined only in the first row and all other rows contain the data for those elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vElems" select=
     "/*/row[1]/elem[normalize-space()]"/>


 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[position() >1]"/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
  <row>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vElems">
    <xsl:with-param name="pValues"
      select="elem"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </row>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="elem">
  <xsl:param name="pValues"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

  <xsl:element name="{.}">
   <xsl:value-of select="$pValues[$vPos]"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document (the provided plus one more data row)**:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <elem>Timestamp</elem>
        <elem>ERB.CHW.BTU_CV</elem>
        <elem>ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV</elem>
        <elem>ERB.HW.BTU_CV</elem>
        <elem>ERB.HW.BTU1_CV</elem>
        <elem>ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV</elem>
        <elem>ERB.KWH.MT_CV</elem>
        <elem></elem>
    </row>
    <row>
        <elem>2011/09/30 11:21:13.9062</elem>
        <elem>2.307609E+09</elem>
        <elem>1880067</elem>
        <elem>1.068635E+08</elem>
        <elem>1340.386</elem>
        <elem>448.8</elem>
        <elem>1427723</elem>
        <elem></elem>
    </row>
    <row>
        <elem>2011/09/31 11:22:33.9063</elem>
        <elem>3.418609E+10</elem>
        <elem>1991073</elem>
        <elem>1.068635E+08</elem>
        <elem>1340.386</elem>
        <elem>452.5</elem>
        <elem>169578</elem>
        <elem></elem>
    </row>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <row>
      <Timestamp>2011/09/30 11:21:13.9062</Timestamp>
      <ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>2.307609E+09</ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>
      <ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>1880067</ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>
      <ERB.HW.BTU_CV>1.068635E+08</ERB.HW.BTU_CV>
      <ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>1340.386</ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>
      <ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>448.8</ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>
      <ERB.KWH.MT_CV>1427723</ERB.KWH.MT_CV>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Timestamp>2011/09/31 11:22:33.9063</Timestamp>
      <ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>3.418609E+10</ERB.CHW.BTU_CV>
      <ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>1991073</ERB.CHW.BTU1_CV>
      <ERB.HW.BTU_CV>1.068635E+08</ERB.HW.BTU_CV>
      <ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>1340.386</ERB.HW.BTU1_CV>
      <ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>452.5</ERB.KW.DEMAND_CV>
      <ERB.KWH.MT_CV>169578</ERB.KWH.MT_CV>
   </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Dimitre.  Your answer - in particular, the part about skipping even `<row>` nodesets - makes me realize that I did not give enough clarity.  I would be grateful if you could read my edit above and modify your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @ABach: Please, have a look at my updated answer -- hope I understood the problem this time :)

Answer (score 2):

The following stylesheet produces the requested result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ignore even-numbered rows -->
    <xsl:template match="row[position() mod 2 = 0]"/>
    <!-- non-empty elem nodes of odd-numbered rows -->
    <xsl:template match="elem[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{text()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::row[1]/elem[$pos]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="elem"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

- The Identity Transform is used to copy most nodes through unchanged
- All even-numbered rows are initially skipped
- When processing the (non-empty) `elem` elements of each odd-numbered row, we grab the value of the `elem` at the same position in the row's following sibling

Comment: Thank you, @lwburk.  Your answer - in particular, the part about skipping even `<row>` nodesets - makes me realize that I did not give enough clarity.  I would be grateful if you could read my edit above and modify your answer.  Thanks!